# Comparing values from both tables inside a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to write an INSERT instruction that gets one of its values from a different table using a subquery with a WHERE clause that compares both tables. It's probably easier to understand by looking at the code.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (f1,f2,f3) 
VALUES ("foo","bar",(SELECT e3 FROM table2 WHERE table2.e2 = table1.f2));
```

I've tried a few combinations but nothing works so far. Can this be done? how?

Comment: you cannot do this! think about it, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question is unclear, which is why sample data and desired results are almost always useful in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want an update?

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.f2 = f2.e2
    set f2 = 'foo',
        f3 = 'bar';
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause in question is a bit odd because value of `table1.f2` doesn't exist yet in the table, it is just about to be inserted (or I misunderstand what the query demonstrates). Maybe you want this instead :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (f1,f2,f3) 
SELECT "foo","bar", e2 
FROM table2 
WHERE table2.e2 = "bar";
```

Above sample demonstrates how to do SQL `INSERT` from `SELECT` statement.

Comment: You understood right, the table doesn't exist yet when the query is made. I've given a look at your solution but it doesn't seem right... why would I select "foo" and "bar"? those are values, not field names, and from table 1, not 2...

Comment: @gulagdandy "foo" and "bar" are hardcoded values, and it is syntactically correct. But if you has it without double-quotes, MySQL understand it as field name instead of string value.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being obtuse, but I don't see how your solution would work. "foo" is not in table2, in fact, table2 only has 3 fields: zipcode, longitute, latitude; while table1 has 15 fields, one of which is zipcode. I was trying to insert all the values in table1 while getting the lat and long values from table2. I'll try updating instead.

Comment: OK, so you're trying to `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`? they are fundamentally different.

Comment: I know; someone asked me to do this as a single insert to "make it more efficient". I've used update and it works fine, issue is solved. Thanks!